# Series expansion of exponential and logarithmic functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that:

$$e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$\log(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n}$$

Where second series converges when $|x-1|<1$.It is possible to prove that:

$$e^{\log(x)}=x$$

for $|x-1|<1$ using $\textbf{only}$ series representation?

Comment: Yes, but it's quite tedious. Just put your series expansion of $\log(x)$ in the one for $e^x$, i.e. $e^{\log(x)}=\sum_n\frac{(\log(x))^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us prove:
$$\exp(-\log(1-z))=\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n.\tag{1}$$
through:
$$-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n}.\tag{2}$$
We can notice that the RHS of $(1)$ is the EGF of the combinatorial class of permutations over $n$ objects, while the RHS of $(2)$ is the EGF of the combinatorial class of cyclic permutations of $n$ objects. Through the [Flajolet-Sedgewick fundamental theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics), we have that $(1)$ is equivalent to the statement:

> Every $\sigma\in S_n$ can be decomposed in a unique way as a product of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\log(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n}\simeq (x-1)-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\\
e^{\log(x)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\log^n(x)}{n!}\simeq 1+\log(x)+\dfrac{\log^2(x)}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\log^3(x)\right)\\
&\simeq 1+\left[(x-1)-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(x-1)^4}{2}-(x-1)^3\right]\\
&\simeq x-(x-1)^3+\dfrac{(x-1)^4}{2}
\end{align}

As $\vert x-1\vert<1$, the leading term is the one with the smallest exponent; therefore:
$$e^{\log(x)}\sim x$$